# Show only Web Application Chat rooms in the sidebar

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I think it is better to show only Chat Rooms related to Web Application to the Web Application Chat Widget. Now it is showing all Chatrooms from http://chat.stackexchange.com/. Visitors may confused if all chatrooms are showing there.

Answer (score 4):

I think some blending is good.  Some of the rooms are not tied to a specific site, like the General Room, Sandbox, Chat Feedback to name a couple.  Perhaps the sidebar could show rooms associated with the specific site and rooms that are not tied to a site?

Comment: It is possible if Rooms have "Tags". Like "Web Application" site only shows the rooms tagged "web-application" or related "web-application". In that case, all common rooms like "General", "Sandbox", "Chat Feedback" have all tags like "web-application", "gaming", "wordpress" etc... Tags may be hidden to the users expect "Moderators"